# How to deal with components inside dynamic html strings in Sapper & Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I am trying to make my first Sapper site and I'm populating the content similarly to how it's done in the template [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/blob/master/src/routes/blog/%5Bslug%5D.html).

My problem is that I want to allow usage of custom components in the content of `{@html post.html}`. Currently it doesn't work, the HTML is just inserted there without being treated like a component, even if I import the component in `[slug].html` and it works if used directly somewhere besides that `{@html post.html}`.

The behaviour is kind of expected as the content is fetched after svelte has finished it's work, but I am not sure what should I do then. I want a couple of custom components like `<FancyButton>` to be usable in the user generated content.

Can I ask the `[slug].html` component to look at the `post.html` or just whole content after insertion and create an instance of child component wherever it should be? Or should I somehow compile the string beforehand on the server?